"TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" but I only passed one for class variable
I have the following class variable:
class Exchange(exchanges.L3Exchange):
    extract_mmt_fields = aquis_extract_mmt_fields

    def write_data(self):
        ...

        update_message = self.extract_mmt_fields(mmt_flag_values)

And in another python package, where I import aquis_extract_mmt_fields from, I have this:
In another python package,aquis_extract_mmt_fields looks like:
 def aquis_extract_mmt_fields(mmt_flag_values):
     ...

The above breaks with:
TypeError: aquis_extract_mmt_fields() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given


self is given as first argument.

Thanks mats, could you suggest what I need to do to get it working?

Do I add self as the first argument in aquis_extract_mmt_fields? That doesn't look right to me

See the duplicate linked on top of your question.

Excellent thank you, it works following their suggestion
